# Unable to use subprocess constants

Tags: python

I cannot find subprocess constants but the package is installed. The following code fails on the second line. Do you know why ?

```
import subprocess
si.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
print si.dwFlags
```

Normally these constants should be in the package (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

I use Python 2.7

Comment: Needless to say you're missing a line from the documentation... (the one that creates `si` first?)

Comment: yes forgot to add it in the example. si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those specific constants are only defined on Windows.

Quoting from the [relevant section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#windows-popen-helpers):

> The `STARTUPINFO` class and following constants are only available on Windows.

The `subprocess` module tests for `sys.platform`; if equal to `win32`, the `STARTUPINFO` and `pywintypes` classes are defined, and the constants are imported from the `_subprocess` module (which is only ever compiled on Windows).

Note that these constants were not added to `subprocess` until Python 2.7.2; if you are running Python 2.7.1 or 2.7.0 you'd have to import them from the `_subprocess` module directly. 2.7.2 and newer include [this bugfix](http://bugs.python.org/issue7838) that exposes these constants, but the [documentation bugfix](http://bugs.python.org/issue11961) failed to mention that the version that these constants were exposed in.

Here is a workaround you can use, that adds these constants for you:

```
if not hasattr(submodule, 'STD_INPUT_HANDLE'):
    import _submodule
    _missing = (
        'STD_INPUT_HANDLE', 'STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE', 'STD_ERROR_HANDLE', 'SW_HIDE',
        'STARTF_USESTDHANDLES', 'STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW')
    for _name in _missing:
        setattr(submodule, _name, getattr(_submodule, _name))
    del _submodule, _name, _missing
```

Comment: Then you need to provide more evidence; traceback of the exception, how you installed Python, if you are perhaps using Cygwin. Your 'workaround' is not a proper problem solution.

Comment: I know it is not a proper workaround. May be a reinstallation would fix it. Somebody ever encountered the same problem ?

Comment: The problem is *very* peculiar. If you didn't get any traceback on importing `subprocess` then it appears something *deleted* the constants imported into the module.

Comment: do you what could cause this ?

Comment: Unknown; another module perhaps. Did you see the comment on your post below? I asked you for the output of `dir(subprocess)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with :

subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

Comment: If `subprocess._subprocess` works but the constant itself is not imported into `subprocess`, then something has badly gone wrong with the import process of that module. What does `import sys; print sys.platform` give?

Comment: This gives me 'win32'

Comment: Can you give me the result of `print dir(subprocess)`?

Comment: >>> import subprocess
>>> print dir(subprocess)
['CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE', 'CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP', 'CalledProcessError', 'MAXFD'
, 'PIPE', 'Popen', 'STARTUPINFO', 'STDOUT', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__'
, '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_active', '_cleanup', '_demo_posix', '
_demo_windows', '_eintr_retry_call', '_subprocess', 'call', 'check_call', 'check
_output', 'gc', 'list2cmdline', 'msvcrt', 'mswindows', 'os', 'pywintypes', 'sign
al', 'sys', 'threading', 'traceback', 'types']

Comment: the constants I am looking for do not appear in the output. subprocess is a built-in module of Python or a separate module ?

Comment: Everything is there *except* most of the constants. The same code that imports `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` also imports `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, so something is **very** fishy here.

Comment: What does `print subprocess.__all__` give you?

Comment: How old is your Python version? I see that a [revision from 2011](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c10d55c51d81/Lib/subprocess.py) does not yet import these constants.

Comment: Right, I am now certain that the problem is that you are using python 2.7.1 or earlier.

Comment: >>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.__all__
['Popen', 'PIPE', 'STDOUT', 'call', 'check_call', 'check_output', 'CalledProcess
Error', 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE', 'CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP']
>>>